# Multiple WatchKit Apps For 1 iOS App

Tags: ios, apple-watch

According to the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaGlance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH5-SW1), developers are only allowed to include 1 glance in their AppleWatch app. This creates a bit of a challenge for me since my app is an aggregate of different types of data so I'm not sure which data set to include in the glance.

That being said, could I get around this by creating multiple AppleWatch apps for my iOS app which would then allow me to create a single glance for each AppleWatch app?

Comment: Is it at least possible for an app to create multiple Apple Watch apps? If it is, you should be sure that it **really** makes sense to have multiple apps.

Comment: Good point.  I was only looking at this option as away to have multiple glances.

Answer (score 2):

No. Confirmed one Watch app per iOS app.

> There is no support for multiple WatchKit apps per iPhone app at this
>   time. 
>   
> - Apple's WatchKit Evangelist

You can implement multiple Glance views depending on the user's context (time and location) using WKInterfaceGroups and hiding/unhiding when necessary.

See my answer to the exact same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214768/3588917

Comment: Thanks, then it is confirmed.  I may give the user an option in the app to select what they want to see in the glance, then at run time hide/show labels at run-time base on what the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

Will a timer work for you?  For example, when a certain time elapsed, you can change the UI of the glance to show a different type of data?  When a user taps a glance, you will be able to tell what data is showing in the glance at the time and pass relevant contextual data and redirect them to an appropriate interface controller?

***"When the user taps a glance, Apple Watch launches the corresponding WatchKit app. Normally, launching the app displays its main interface controller. If you want to display a different interface controller at launch time, call the updateUserActivity:userInfo: method from your glance interface controller and use it to provide contextual information about what the glance is doing. At launch time, your app can use that contextual data to display a different interface controller."***

Comment: Good idea but I think this defeats the purpose of the glance. What I may do is allow the user to select which data point in the app they would like to see in the glance.