# Can we create multiple glance interfaces in a single Watchkit app?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am trying to create a WatchKit App that needs to show multiple pieces of information to the users in form of glances.Is there a way to create multiple glances in such an app.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make more than one glance per application

But nothing prevents you from creating one glance, that will contain all possible states of "each glance type", and then, in runtime perform hide/show of specific components of the glance.

```
Glance  
  Top Group
    State1
    State2 (hidden)
    StateN (hidden)    
  Bottom Group 
    State1
    State2 (hidden)
    StateN (hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be only one glance in a WatchKit App. Try to put another Glance Interace Controller into interface storyboard and try to compile. Xcode will give you an error: "Illegal Configuration. The application may only contain a single glance interface". The official documentation is also telling only about one glance per app.

Comment: However, Twitter's Apple Watch Glance has a "type" option. I assume they're using some sort of private API that Apple are allowing.

Comment: The OP is clearly not asking about multiple instances of the `WKInterfaceController` in the app, but rather "a way to create multiple glances"...

Answer (score 0):

you can add page based glance to your glance interface and add pages to the glance interface builder and u can see many pages...

Answer (score 0):

You can only has one glance Inter face but you can setting the element on the glance inter face using the glanceInterfacecController.swift

Answer (score 0):

According to the WatchKit Programming Guide 1 Glance Interface Controller per app.

> An app has only one glance interface controller, so that one controller must be able to display the data you want. 
>   Focus on the most important data.

There is nothing stated in the guidelines to prevent you from implementing multiple 'hidden' WKInterfaceGroups in your Glance Controller and unhiding the most relevant group needed based on the current context (time, location) of the user.

```
[myLabel setHidden:NO];
```